# track by $index causes a bunch of empty objects

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, ng-view

I have an error:

> ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater

To solve that problem, I used `track by $index` like this:

```
contact in contacts track by $index
```

but the thing is that I have new error like this.

[image]

what happened to my app now?

Comment: Post your contacts array data. It seems contacts is not an array. And ng-repeat only works with array

Comment: as @Ved suggested we can comment or answer after seeing the data of contacts

Comment: contacts data is from $http.get() so it is like $scope.contacts = response;

Comment: and this is the schema model of my contact. var contactSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 email: String,
 phone: String
}, { collection: 'contact' });